# ActionPack Generator for 3.0

Tags: subsonic, generator, actionpack

IS there a actionpack/subsonic generator for 3.0 like there was for 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

No. All code generation for SubSonic is handled through T4 templates: http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Setting_up_SubSonic_3.0